# Soql-builder - Datetime issue

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I have been trying to write a dynamic soql query by using soql-builder

http://richardvanhook.com/2010/04/11/soql-builder/

But, I am stuck while assigning date as criteria while constructing the query.

Here is the code.

```
Date endOfDate = Date.today();
Date startOfDate = Date.today().addMonths(-1);

Time startTime = Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0);
Time endTime = Time.newInstance(23, 59, 59, 0);


DateTime startDate = DateTime.newInstance(startOfDate ,startTime);
System.debug('DEBUG: StartDate : '+startDate); // DEBUG: StartDate : 2014-03-07 05:00:00

DateTime endDate = DateTime.newInstance(endOfDate ,endTime);
System.debug('DEBUG: EndDate : '+endDate); //DEBUG: EndDate : 2014-04-09 03:59:59
```

But, after query constructed by using soql-builder. Debug came like this :

```
(CreatedDate >= 2014-03-07T12:00:00Z AND CreatedDate <= 2014-04-07T11:59:59Z)
```

Actual:

```
startdate came 2014-03-07T12:00:00Z

endDate came 2014-04-07T11:59:59Z
```

Expected :

```
startdate 2014-03-07T00:00:00Z

endDate 2014-04-07T23:59:59Z
```

Anyone please give some light, why output is coming like this in soql-builder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening is that you're creating the times in your local time zone, but getting the string value in UTC. When I run your code, I get

```
StartDate : 2014-03-07 08:00:00
EndDate : 2014-04-08 06:59:59
```

because I'm on Pacific Time.

To get the results you're expecting, change `DateTime.newInstance()` to `DateTime.newInstanceGmt()`. This gives me the result

```
StartDate : 2014-03-07 00:00:00
EndDate : 2014-04-07 23:59:59
```